# Adding MALLET to the Bash path

Tags: bash, unix, path, mallet

I have run into a problem with adding the MALLET topic modelling tool to my path.

If I `cd` to `/mallet-2.0-8/` and type `./bin/mallet`, all works fine.

If I type `echo $PATH`, I have successfully added `'/mallet-2.0.8/bin'` to the path. But typing `mallet` now at the prompt yields `-bash: mallet: command not found`.

So, how to get the `$` to respond to `mallet`?

Comment: Did you manually add the `mallet` path to `$PATH` in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I manually added it to the `.bash_profile` by using the `nano`editor. The line I added was `PATH="/mallet-2.0.8/bin:${PATH}"`

Comment: Did you `source` the `.bash_profile` from the current shell to make the changes take effect right away? `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: are you sure `mallet` is an executable in that directory?

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia This is what it looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yomw7bgkwbqfb2/Screen%20Shot%202017-03-20%20at%2011.26.07%20copy.png?dl=0

Comment: @Inian Yes, I sourced it.

Comment: So, yes, there is a `mallet` executable in that folder, but one must  write `./bin/mallet`with a `.` in the `mallet-2.0-8/` folder to run it manually. Using `cd`down into the `/bin`and then entering `mallet`does not work...

Comment: Are you sure you have no spaces in the filename?

Answer (score 1):

The line you have to add to the `bashrc` or `bash_profile` is:

```
export PATH="/mallet-2.0.8/bin:$PATH"
```

if you do not use the `export` the variable will be defined only inside the file.

You can also try by writing the same line directly in the shell.

Comment: Tried both these things, but same problem. It seems I have definitely been able to add the path correctly by the behaviour described in my previous comment is what needs to be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the mallet to the path variable, make sure to source it. Here are the steps I have followed.

[image: Issue with bin\mallet]

1. Added MAVEN_HOME to the path. This is the Exact Command.

export PATH="/mallet-2.0.8/bin:$PATH"

2. Make sure that the same directory has been added. (Try to Echo $PATH)
3. Then source the bash_profile.

source ~/.bash_profile.

Now,

[image: Resolved.]